# dynamo db cloudformation template error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I get the following error when I try to load this cloudformation template to create a dynamo db table

Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "TableName": {
      "Description": "Table name to use",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "test-user-unique-ids"
    },
    "ReadCapacityUnits": {
      "Description": "Provisioned read throughput",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": "100",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10000",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10000"
    },
    "WriteCapacityUnits": {
      "Description": "Provisioned write throughput",
      "Type": "Number",
      "Default": "100",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10000",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10000"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "testUserUniqueIds": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "TableName": {
          "Ref": "TableName"
        },
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "unique_id",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "guid",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": {
            "Ref": "ReadCapacityUnits"
          },
          "WriteCapacityUnits": {
            "Ref": "WriteCapacityUnits"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute name is defined as `unique_id`. However, the hash key has been defined for attribute `guid`.

The attribute names defined on `AttributeDefinitions` and the same should be used on `KeySchema`. They should be consistent.

Either keep `unique_id` or `guid` on both `AttributeDefinitions` and `KeySchema`.

**Edit:**

While creating the Dynamodb table, you can include only key attributes such as partition key and sort key if available. The whole concept of nosql database is that each item I.e. record can have different attributes. You don't need to define the non key attributes while creating the table. NoSQL is a schema less database.

If you specify any non key attributes while creating the table, you will get validation exception.

Comment: How to add additional columns to the table? I want to add columns for unique_id and guid and service

Comment: And you say there is no way to make the primary key and object or array or even the secondary key

Comment: Comment is not clear. Am just adding more info. Simply, only key attributes can be defined while creating the table. If you have any GSI (Global Secondary Index), the key attributes of GSI can be defined while creating the table as well. Any attribute which is not part of key (either main table or index) can't be defined while creating the table.

Comment: Can we make the key or secondary index an array or object?

Comment: No, DynamoDB doesn't support. You can't create index on document data types such as Set, Map, List, Array etc.